# How to invoke a jenkins pipeline B, in between if-else condition of jenkins pipeline A?

Tags: shell-script, docker, jenkins

jenkins pipeline-A

```
pipeline{
  stage('deploy'){
    agent { label 'slave' }
  steps{
    script{
      if [ "$deployenv" = dev ];
      then 
        echo 'restart not required'
      elif [ "$deployenv" = qa ];
      then
        echo "restart required"
        //need to invoke another jenkins pipeline-B here
      fi
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell Command to Execute Build or Pipeline can be inserted into your Shell Script in Pipeline A, at the Point where you want to invoke the Pipeline B.

The Point where you want to trigger Pipeline B could use either "SSH" or "Curl" or "Java CLI Client" to use JENKINS API to control this.

### With SSH:

```
ssh -l USERNAME -p JENKINSPORT SERVER COMMAND ## Pipeline B should be the COMMAND here
```

[[ Initially, you have to enable the SSH Access and configure the Authentication ]]

**Reference** : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#ssh

### With Java CLI Client:

Download the Client via :

```
JENKINS_URL/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
```

Execute via :

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar [-s JENKINS_URL] [global options...] command [command options...] [arguments...] ## Pipeline B should be the COMMAND here
```

**Reference** : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#using-the-cli-client

### With Curl:

Something like this:

```
curl -X POST http://....:8080/job/....
```

With username & credentials,

```
curl -X POST --user <jenkins_username>:<jenkins_API_key> http://<jenkins_server_url>/job/<your_jenkins_job_name>/build ## Pipeline B should be the COMMAND here
```

**Reference** : https://myopswork.com/when-shell-scripts-meets-jenkins-61594f576e96